# Can find "15" in "155", but not "55"

Tags: regex-greedy

The expression `/\d5/g` , matches with "15" in "155", but not "55".

How do I modify the expression so it matches with "15" and "55" in "155"?

---

Apparently, I have to do something called a "lookahead assertion".

```
let str = '155';
let regEx = /(?=(\d5))/g;
let matches = str.matchAll(regEx);
```

Comment: Regex doesn't define a way to match overlapping matches, so not all parsers support it. What parser are you using (ie where are you using your regex)?

Comment: Javascript. Node v15.9.

Comment: Yep. That explains lookahead assertion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your parser, but maybe you have to say, that the "5" can occure more-times.

Something like this:

```
let regEx = /(?=(\d5)*)/g;
```